# "errmsg": "db already exists with different case already have: [Test] trying to create [test]"

Tags: mongodb

Hi I'm getting this error when I try to post. Don"t understand what's going on

```
{
    "driver": true,
    "name": "MongoError",
    "index": 0,
    "code": 13297,
    "errmsg": "db already exists with different case already have: [Test] trying to create [test]"
}
```

It has something to do with an existing database I previously created however in my clusters my collections are empty.

EDIT: I fixed it by changing the nameof my database

```js
 mongoose.connect(mongoUrl, {
        dbName : 'name',
        ...
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you created a database called `test` previously, and are now trying to use database called `Test`, and you are using a case-insensitive file system (Windows?).

In this situation `test` and `Test` would collide on the filesystem, and MongoDB is refusing to allow both to exist.

Comment: Is a way I can maybe rename that database before posting ? @Oleg

Comment: Have you tried searching for how to rename a database?

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the database by creating a clone, a lengthy process:

1. Copy the original database by copying all the collections, views, and buckets in it.
2. Create a new database.
3. Name the new database as desired.
4. Paste the copied collections, views, and buckets into the new database.
5. Drop the original database.